# How to find which was the wrong message in a Message Not Understood message?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I want to find the name of the message that triggered the MNU , how do I do that ?

For example if I do

```
Transcript explode .
```

This will trigger a MNU because method explode does not exist but how do I find that the name of the message that triggered MNU is "explode" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I DoIt that, I get a debugger. The title there is

```
MessageNotUnderstood: ThreadSafeTranscript>>explode
```

When I select the first element, I get to see the doesNotUnderstand: aMessage, where aMessage is the message

Comment: wow nice, thanks for the answer it works :) all I had to do was to override doesNotUnderstand as you suggested :)

Comment: Don't use `#messageNotUnderstood` too lightly. 1. Control flow may become hard to track and 2. it's the last resort after traversing the class hierarchy and all exception handlers and may be slow under certain conditions.

Comment: I am using it to parse pharo code to python code as string so something like -> Bpy data objects:'Cube' location: '(1.0 2.0 3.0)' turns into a python string 'bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location = (1.0 2.0 3.0)' which then python executes as python code. If you have better alternative all I am all ears :)

Comment: You might want to take a look at how the Seaside canvas works. That is explicit, which is way easier to debug. @MaxLeske has right. Limit the scope where you apply metaprogramming

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

[Transcript explode]
    on: MessageNotUnderstood
    do: [:ex| ex message selector]

The exception's message is an instance of Message.  It understands selector arguments etc.

Remember that the exception is an epiphenomenon.  The VM actually sends doesNotUnderstand: aMessage when a message is not understood, and the doesNotUnderstand: method in Object raises the exception.  The argument to doesNotUnderstand: is a message, and is of curse the same as that in the exception.  That means you can implement your own doesNotUnderstand: message in your own class if you have special requirements.