# How to find a chain of MessageNotUnderstood messages

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Following up from my previous example here

[How to find which was the wrong message in a Message Not Understood message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831610/how-to-find-which-was-the-wrong-message-in-a-message-not-understood-message)

Let's say that the code now is this

```
Transcript explode implode andBecomeNuclear.
```

Pharo will send 3 MNUs in this case: 1) explode 2) implode 3) andBecomeNuclear

Overriding doesNotUnderstand: does not help here because I want the full chain of messages. That means I want it to give me not just one message but all 3 messages together till it finds the period that ends the pharo command.

How I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all Pharo will not send 3 messages. Following priority order it will send `explode` and then stop with DNU, or send `implode` to returned object. What you can do is define DNU in a way that stores messages in a queue and return self. I don't know how to retrieve all chain in the end of a statement. The easiest way would be to define some message like `chain` that will return the whole queue.

Comment: thanks Uko , yes I was thinking doing exactly the same but I have no clue how to detect when a pharo statement ends. Still a vote up from me :)

Comment: You can't detect the '.' if that's what you mean. Usually, we have a special message at the end that is really implemented in the class. E.g., #send